# Can testcontainers be used without internet access?

Tags: testcontainers

Good day!
Can testcontainers be used without internet access? I downloaded the required containers. They start and run. In this case, when running tests, an error occurs. I have no internet access

Code

```
container = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>().withCapabilities(Capabilities.getFirefoxOptions()).withRecordingMode(
          webDriverForm.get().isVideoError() ? VncRecordingMode.RECORD_FAILING : VncRecordingMode.RECORD_ALL,
          new File(webDriverForm.get().getVideoPath()), VncRecordingFormat.MP4);

ontainer.start();
WebDriver driver = container.getWebDriver();
```

Error

```
2021-09-27 17:54:47 INFO  Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 20.10.8
  API Version: 1.41
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 12700 MB
2021-09-27 17:54:47 INFO  Image name substitution will be performed by: DefaultImageNameSubstitutor (composite of 'ConfigurationFileImageNameSubstitutor' and 'PrefixingImageNameSubstitutor')
2021-09-27 17:54:48 INFO  Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for index.docker.io
2021-09-27 17:54:49 ERROR Error during callback
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host"}

       at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247)
       at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Когда пользователь открывает страницу по параметру "https://confluence.ca.sbrf.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=240980441"                                                     # CommonStepDefinitionsGUI.loginInFs(String)
      com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Status 500: {"message":"Get \"https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host"}

       at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.execute(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:247)
       at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.github.dockerjava.core.DefaultInvocationBuilder.lambda$executeAndStream$1(DefaultInvocationBuilder.java:269)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
       at ✽.пользователь открывает страницу по параметру "https://confluence.ca.sbrf.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=240980441"(file:src/test/resources/features/CSA-T1405_Проверка_отображения_Соответствует.feature:6)
```

Only saved containers can be run in docker.

Containers in Docker

```
alpine      3.14    14119a10abf4    about 1 month ago   5.6 MB  
docker/getting-started      latest  083d7564d904    4 months ago    27.99 MB    
hello-world     latest  feb5d9fea6a5    4 days ago  13.26 KB    
hello-world     <none>  d1165f221234    7 months ago    13.34 KB    
redis       5.0.3-alpine    3d2a373f46ae    over 2 years ago    50.83 MB    
selenium/standalone-chrome-debug        2.45.0  d7852787b42a    over 6 years ago    750.74 MB   
selenium/standalone-firefox-debug       2.45.0  a86fa79ad0c8    over 6 years ago    594.67 MB   
testcontainers/ryuk     0.3.2   b24c56207c68    about 2 months ago  11.95 MB    
testcontainers/vnc-recorder     1.1.0   e51c318c86f4    over 1 year ago 306.86 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no internet access from your network you have to setup your own docker hub. And you have to upload docker containers there via:

```
docker tag
docker push
```

commands